# Reading from sqlite DB using form answers when using Flask

Tags: python, sqlite, flask

I apologize ahead of time, I'm sure this is a silly question.  I wanted to try and teach myself Flask over the weekend but I hit my first hurdle. Here is a basic idea of my program:

- Large database named plugin.db
- Finished the flask tutorial, and now I'm using those files for reference when writing my own.
- Currently my application works (meaning it doesn't crash), but nothing is coming back when I attempt to query my sqlite database.

Here is my main code:

```
import os
import sqlite3
from flask import Flask, request, session, g, redirect, url_for, abort, \
 render_template, flash

app = Flask(__name__)
app.config.from_object(__name__)

# Load default config and override config from an environment variable
app.config.update(dict(
    DATABASE=os.path.join(app.root_path, 'plugin.db'),
))
app.config.from_envvar('PLUGINDB_SETTINGS', silent=True)

def connect_db():
    """Connects to the specific database."""
    rv = sqlite3.connect(app.config['DATABASE'])
    rv.row_factory = sqlite3.Row
    return rv

def init_db():
    with app.app_context():
        db = get_db()
        with app.open_resource('schema.sql', mode='r') as f:
            db.cursor().executescript(f.read())
        db.commit()

@app.cli.command('initdb')
def initdb_command():
    """Initializes the database."""
    init_db()
    print 'Initialized the database.'

def get_db():
    """Opens a new database connection if there is none yet for 
    the current application context
    """
    if not hasattr(g, 'sqlite_db'):
        g.sqlite_db = connect_db()
    return g.sqlite_db

@app.teardown_appcontext
def close_db(error):
    """Closes the database again at the end of the request."""
    if hasattr(g, 'sqlite_db'):
        g.sqlite_db.close()

@app.route("/",methods=["GET","POST"])
@app.route("/index",methods=["GET","POST"])
def index():
    db = get_db()
    cur = db.execute('select * from t0109161144 where pluginID is 19506')
    plugins = cur.fetchall()
    return render_template("index.html")

@app.route('/query', methods=["GET","POST"])
def script_id():
    db = get_db()
    script_id = request.form['script_id']
    plugin_info = dependencies(script_id)
    return redirect(url_for('index'))

def dependencies(script_id):
    db = get_db()
    dependencies = db.execute("select * from t0109161144 where pluginID is (script_id) values (?)', (script_id)
    return dependencies
```

My script has become quite crowded along the way while I was testing a few different things.  Here is my current index.html:

```
{% extends "layout.html" %}
{% block body %}
    <form action="{{ url_for('index') }}" method=post class=index>
      <dl>
        <dt>Plugin ID:
        <dd><input type=text size=30 name=script_id>
        <dd><input type=submit value=Query>
      </dl>
    </form>
  <ul class=plugins>
  {% for plugin in plugins %}
    <li><h2>{{ plugin.pluginID }}</h2>{{ plugin.pluginname|safe }}
  {% else %}
    <li><em>Unbelievable.  No entries here so far</em>
  {% endfor %}
  </ul>
{% endblock %}
```

What I'm trying to do is this:

- User searches by plugin ID (or other variables that I will worry about later) in the text box.
- The value entered by the user is then used to query the database and return results.

I tried to hardcode a known good value, but that isn't even showing up on index.html:

```
cur = db.execute('select * from t0109161144 where pluginID is 19506')
```

After posting here, I can see where I definitely have unnecessary code, but I would just like this one part of the application working and then I'll work on cleaning up the code.  Any pointers or advice would be greatly appreciated, thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You aren't passing `plugins` to your template. The last line of `index` should be

```
return render_template("index.html", plugins=plugins)
```

Comment: Wow... this is exactly what it was, thank you so much!  Trying to wrap my head around all this.  Thanks again!